# Bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel der Überschriften

Tags: grammaticality, article

Ich habe sehr häufig Überschriften wie *Gründe des Alkoholmissbrauchs*, *Maßnahmen der Bekämpfung gegen Doping* gesehen. Ich verstehe aber nicht:

1. Warum braucht man in diesen Überschriften keine Artikel?
2. Wenn ich im Singular schreibe, z. B. *Grund*, *Maßnahme*, dann brauche ich einen Artikel, richtig?

Comment: "Außerdem wollte ich auch wissen, dass die Grammatik hier anders als die in Englisch, oder?" - es ist nicht klar, was damit gemeint ist. Ja, die Grammatik der deutschen Sprache ist anders als die der englischen Sprache. Aber sicherlich meinst du einen bestimmten Aspekt?

Comment: Danke. Ich habe die Frage weggelassen, da die eher nach englischen Grammatik fragt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Plural des unbestimmten Artikels im Deutschen ist    (eine Leerstelle):

```
            Singular  Plural
  bestimmt  das Haus  die Häuser
unbestimmt  ein Haus      Häuser
```

> Er baut die Häuser. (Er baut diese Häuser, nicht jene anderen.)
> Er baut Häuser. (Häuser bauen ist sein Beruf.)

Auch das Englische hat keinen unbestimmten Artikel im Plural:

```
            Singular   Plural
  bestimmt  the house  the houses
unbestimmt    a house      houses
```

> He builds houses.

Im Französischen dageben gibt es einen unbestimmten Artikel im Plural:

```
            Singular  Plural
  bestimmt  le livre  les livres
unbestimmt  un livre  des livres
```

> Il aime les livres. "Er mag diese Bücher."
> Il aime des livres. "Er mag Bücher."

Früher hat man in Buchtiteln oft, wenn es um Dinge im Plural ging, *einige* anstelle eines unbestimmten Artikels verwendet:

> Über einige Grundfragen der Philosophie der Politik
> Anmerkungen über einige Lehrsätze der Wolfischen Metaphysik

Im Französischen und Englischen genauso:

> Lettre sur quelques points fondamentaux du Protestantisme (*quelques* "einige")
> Some Applications of Weighted Sobolev Spaces

So hätten die von dir genannten Bücher vor zweihundert Jahren vermutlich Titel dieser Art gehabt:

> Über einige Gründe des Alkoholmissbrauchs
> Einige Maßnahmen der Bekämpfung gegen Doping*

Wenn es dagegen um einen Gegenstand geht, dann braucht man im Deutschen einen Artikel:

> Der Grund des Alkoholmissbrauchs
> Ein Grund für Alkoholmissbrauch

Verwendest du den bestimmten Artikel (hier *der*), sagst du damit, dass es nur einen Grund für Alkoholmissbrauch gibt. Verwendest du den unbestimmten Artikel (hier *ein*), gehst du zwar von mehreren Gründen aus, stellst in deinem Buch aber nur einen davon vor. Dasselbe gilt natürlich im Plural: *Die Gründe des A.* behandelt alle Gründe für A. Dagegen behandeln *Gründe des A.*  und *Über einige Gründe des A.* nur ausgewählte Gründe für A.

---

* "Bekämpfung gegen Doping" empfinde ich als ungrammatisch. Ich würde "Bekämpfung von Doping" oder "Bekämpfung des Doping" schreiben.